# Compressed water

Tags: fluid-dynamics, water

Normally, water is incompressible, but what happens if I have a fixed volume and keep pumping water into it?

Let's say I have a compartment full of water. The compartment is completely sealed off, with only one entrance where a pump is connected. What will happen if the pump keeps running, pumping water into the compartment even though it is full? Will the pressure rise? and is there a formula for this?

Comment: It is not difficult to search for water compressibility and to compute the pressure needed to add the given extra volume of water. Most pump cannot provide such pressure, unless the given relative extra volume is extremely small.

Comment: The specs on the pump will tell you when it stops actually pumping water in...

Comment: For a thin shelled container, this is what happens.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6DvWDCmbPxs

Answer (score 3):

for a positive displacement pump with a small motor on it, pumping into an enclosed volume will stall the pump. in the case of a large motor, it will burst the container, split the pipes, or break a connecting rod inside the pump mechanism.

For a non-positive displacement pump (like an impeller pump) the flow will stop but the pump keeps running, agitating the water inside the pump scroll. with a big enough motor, the impeller blades will begin whipping the water into vapor, a condition called *cavitation*.

In no instance of an ordinary mechanical pump working against water will the bulk compressibility of the water enter into the model of the pump/water system. For that to be significant you need high explosives machined into *shaped charges*.

Comment: Assuming infinite strong material and a pump the pressure will not increase inside the tank then ?

Comment: @Nil, the pump will be able to provide some pressure difference (head).   The pump will be able to raise the pressure inside the tank by that amount.   After that, the pump cannot push any more water in.

Answer (score 1):

For a fixed volume maintained at room temperature and a sufficiently strong pump, the water would tend to solidify (at equilibrium) into [ice-VI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ice_VI) at a pressure of ~1 GPa:

[image]

The compression would tend to generate heating, as would the phase change.